# Spring batch: partition reader called another time

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-batch

I have to migrate some data from a database to another and I'm using Spring Batch with partition. The configuration of the job is the following

```
...
...
<bean id="migrationProcessor" class="it.migrazione.MigrazioneProcessor" scope="step"/>
<bean id="migrationWriter" class="it.migrazione.MigrazioneWriter" scope="step"/>
<bean id="migrationReader" class="it.migrazione.MigrazioneReader" scope="step"/>

<bean id="partitioner" class="it.migrazione.MigrazionePartitioner" />

<bean id="taskExecutor" class="org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor"/>

<bean id="threadPoolTaskExecutor" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
    <property name="corePoolSize" value="10" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="10" />
    <property name="allowCoreThreadTimeOut" value="true" />
</bean>

<job id="migrationJob" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
    <step id="masterStep">
    <partition step="slave" partitioner="partitioner">
        <handler grid-size="10" task-executor="threadPoolTaskExecutor" />
    </partition>
    </step>
</job>

<step id="slave" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
    <tasklet throttle-limit="1" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
        <chunk reader="migrationReader" 
               processor="migrationProcessor"
               writer="migrationWriter" 
               commit-interval="1"/>
    </tasklet>
</step>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>
...
...
```

Job knows how many row must be migrated, so the partitioner creates 10 contexts with a specific range related

```
for (int threadCount = 1; threadCount <= gridSize; threadCount++) {
      if (threadCount == 1)
        fromRow = 0;
      else
        fromRow = toRow + 1;
      toRow += delta;

      context = new ExecutionContext();
      context.putInt("fromRow", fromRow);
      context.putInt("toRow", toRow);
      context.putString("name", "Processing Thread" + threadCount);
      result.put("partition" + threadCount, context);

      logger.info("Partition number >> " + threadCount + " from Row#: "
              + fromRow + " to Row#: " + toRow);
}
```

When I run this job I have some threads that read another time. For example Thread#1 call another time the reader,processor and writer while. I don't understand why, but is it possible to have one thread that executes once the chunk, without checking that read is already called? When the writer related to a specific partition ends, why the thread calls the reader another time? It is like reader doesn't immediately see the changes made by writer.

Comment: Since you are using a ThreadPool, couldn't it be, that one thread just processes two different partitions?

Comment: It's possible, but anyway I don't understand how I can configure it to have one thread related to one partition and nothing else

Comment: Use a SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor instead of a ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.

Comment: Same result. It is like reader doesn't immediately see the changes made by writer.

Comment: What do you mean by "immediately see the changes made by writer"? You pass a query to the reader, the reader executes the query and after that reads the selected items. But as soon as the first element is read, the set of selected entries are fixed. You cannot change this set, regardless, what you are doing in your writer...

Comment: In the writer I change a field of the items used to know if it's already processed. When the reader is called for the second time find the items with these field unset.

Comment: Of course it is. Again, the rows that are selected AND also the data for every row are defined before the reader returns the first element via its read-method. These selected entries AND data will not change afterwards. Your commit in the writer is done in another transaction, this will not influence the already selected elements.

Comment: I have to read and write on the same transaction, because I write the same data I'm reading (in addition to other things). Is it possible to share the same transaction?